# Php CronTab not showing any errors

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

I have created a crontab

```
13 10 * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/data-capture/public/device_2_app.php  >> /var/www/html/data-capture/public/unique_app_tables2.txt
```

the text file shows all the data which has been echoed . But if any error is genrated in php . It is not visible in the text file .

I have switched on the following

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

If i run this device_2_app.php file directly in the browser it gives the error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$mongodate' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/data-capture/public/device_2_app.php on line 7
```

But no error is visible in *unique_app_tables2.txt*

Comment: can you show the code to check

Comment: I have manually  added a semicolon error in it . So that the error is visible .

Comment: what do you mean with this comment? update so that it is clear what happened and if [my] answer helped

Answer (score 0):

The message you are getting:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$mongodate' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   /var/www/html/data-capture/public/device_2_app.php on line 7

Is not standard output but standard error.

If you want to store this as well, you need to redirect standard error:

```
13 10 * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/.../device_2_app.php  2>> /tmp/myerror >> /var/www/html/data-capture/public/unique_app_tables2.txt
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

To understand this better, check these

```
* * * * * ls /tmp/asdfas >> /tmp/err
* * * * * ls /tmp/asdfas2 2>> /tmp/err2
```

The first won't store anything in `/tmp/err`, whereas the second will because the stderr is redirected.

Further reading: [Logging ALL stderr output of crontab to file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29761/40596).